# How to Convert the Lead without creating the Contact

Tags: apex

I have this use case,
When we convert the "LEAD" -- we have two options
Create person account
Create contact and Business Account
What we want to do is to create a a) Person Account and b) Business Account, but not a contact.
What are possible options to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As per the Salesforce [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sales_features_core_leads_convert_to_bus_and_pers_acct.htm&release=230&type=5), you can use `setRelatedPersonAccountRecord` (available after Spring '21) to set the Person Account.

You need to use `setAccountId` and `setRelatedPersonAccountRecord` to set the Business Account and Person Account respectively from the [LeadConvert](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_dml_convertLead.htm) class.